# Calculated Formula to mirror status

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, calculated-column-formula

I have created a custom list with a dropdown field called Project Status with the following options

- Unassigned
- Work in Progress
- Hold
- Dropped
- Completed

I have also created another hidden field which is called current status with the following calculation

```
=IF([Project Status]="Dropped","Dropped",
IF([Project Status]="Work in Progress","Work in Progress",
IF([Project Status]="Hold","Hold",
IF([Project Status]="Completed","Completed"))))
```

but the calculation is not working as the Current Status field isn't been populated when I update the Project Status field

This is part of larger workflow

Comment: This worked also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not to do all this.

you just need write below formula for your field Current Status.

```
=[Project Status]
```

Since you just need replica, you can use the column value as is.

Comment: most welcome mate